# Temporarily enlarge SQL Server command queue

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Using SQL Server 2008 R2

Is it possible to enlarge the command queue and/or the wait time limit for a command to execute?

I have this simple application which do not exhaust the SQL Server, but from time to time there are many concurrent similar request almost the same time, which some reach deadlocks.

Reliability (being sure commands are executed) is much more important for me than performance (I do not mind if the commands will execute in a few seconds of delay).

Is there a switch or a command to allow many more commands reside in a queue until executed or there is some way to make time limit before deadlocks [temporarily] much longer[, as soon as a specific type command is executed] (commands may programmed as stored procedures)?

---

Edit:

Amazingly, using `with (tablockx)` solved my problem.

Can someone explain?

I'll put that as an answer, but will not take credit for it (will not mark it as an answer)

Comment: You mean command an connection timeouts? That is a client side setting that the programmer / connection string can set.

Comment: A *deadlock* isn't something that time alone can resolve. If you have deadlocks occurring, you need to find ways to prevent them from happening - waiting longer isn't one of those ways.

Comment: @tomtom - There are two servers, the SQL server and a web server. the web server is the only one who sends requests to the SQL server. can i set the web server to ask for longer time for an SQL command? if yes, how? Remember, I just want to avoid the deadlocks.

Comment: @damien-the-unbeliever - Can you give me any directions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of this question. I've reach a solution to my problem.

I solved my problem using `with (tablockx)`

The question is broader then my problem, therefore it is not a full answer.

I do not take credit for this answer as THE answer.